# Regex to get the full word using part of the word

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to print the entire word using part of the word.

So far, I've tried this code which is only printing the word 'Javacode'. I'm trying to get the full word 'myJavacode'.

```
var body = 'I want to print myJavacode by seaching the  word java';

var reg = /[\ ,!@#$%^&*()\.\"]*(Java.*?)[\ ,!@#$%^&*()\d\.\"]/g;
var match;

while (match = reg.exec(body)) {
    System.out.println(match[1]);
}
```

Expected result is:-  myJavacode

Comment: It could be java11.

Comment: `var reg = /\w*Java\w*/g;` or `var reg = /[a-zA-Z]*Java[a-zA-Z]*/g;`